# Как строковую переменную превратить в переменную типа даты ( в миллисекундах)

Tags: javascript

на вход переменная строковая:

```
let begin= "24.12.2019";
```

Есть переменная  даты в миллисекундах  (getTime):

```
let date=1577433983031;
```

Как строковую переменную превратить в  переменную типа даты ( в миллисекундах), чтобы можно было сравнить эти переменные?

```
begin<date
```

Comment: можно воспользоваться возможностями либы `momentjs`

Answer (score 3):

`(new Date(begin.split('.').reverse().join('-'))).getTime()`